# CodeIgniter : accessing views from sub folders

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, view, models, controllers

I am trying to learn codeigniter in these days and I am struggling understanding the structure of views, controllers and models according to routes in order to maintain security.

So, how should we structure our views, controllers and models for admin backend and user backend, i mean folders, sub-folders and routing?

first I wanna mention how i am putting my files in order :
My route :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'site/home';
$route['home'] = 'site/home';
```

so here a default controller is Site.php :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function index()
{
    $data['body']='site/home';
    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
}

public function home(){

    $data['body']='site/home';
    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);

}

public function AnotherMethod(){

    $data['body']='site/AnotherPage';
    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);

}
```

And my view template is (views/includes/template.php) :

```
<?php
//load head
$this->load->view('includes/header');

//load body
$this->load->view($body);

//load footer
$this->load->view('includes/footer');

?>
```

**So If i am putting things like this, I am having problem to accessing views from sub folders. As an example,**

```
directory : views/site/userbackend/index.php
or views/site/adminbackend/index.php
```

And there are also controllers and models in sub folders according to the admin backend and user backend.

**How i am going to access them?**

I am here just trying to show what kind of problems i am having..
So now all the answers of the questions can be solved if you just direct me to the scenario how experts do and structure there components and what is the best practices.

I know i have made this question complex with many things at a time, i am sorry for that, if you want me to be clear more on one subject just tell me, i will update my question.

Need a helping hand here.
Thanks in Advance !

Comment: http://developers.ph/codeigniter/hmvc-pattern-codeigniter-php-framework/ this might help

Comment: @MalikMudassar thanks for the link, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

All views are available to all controllers, if:

1. View file exists
2. You specify the correct path to it

For `views/site/userbackend/index.php` should be `$data['body'] = 'site/userbackend/index';`

---

If my simple projects I have this structure:

```
controllers
   backend
      Admin.php
      Admin_users.php
      ...
   Main.php
   News.php
   ...
views
   backend
      main
        header.php
        footer.php
      users
        view_list.php
        view_form.php
   frontend
     main
        header.php
        footer.php
        sidebar.php
     news
        view_list.php
        view_item.php
     mainpage.php
   ...
```

In view_list.php:

```
$this->load->view('frontend/main/header');
<news list>
$this->load->view('frontend/main/footer');
```

And I practice HMVC.

Comment: In your case, can you just show me in short how you will request Admin controller to load backend view (view_list.php) with the help of routing?

Comment: Routing in CodeIgniter is only applicable to controllers. In my projects I always use direct path to view.
But if you want, you can do your own routing for views. You can even extend the CI_Loader as MY_Loader with function view() and conditions. If you want to know current controller and method:
`$router =& load_class('Router');
$controller = $router->fetch_class();
$method = $router->fetch_method();`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and got it working for views in subfolders by adding `.php` to the view path, just like this:

```
$this->load->view('includes/template.php',$data);
```